# Can not get mails from gitlab server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gitlab

Because my gitlab server has problems with Nginx

So I ran the gitlab server manually `rails s -p 1999 -e production`

However I can not get the mails from the server anymore,

The exact setting in another Rails website can work perfectly,

I don't know what's wrong in my gitlab server

Here my `config/environments/production.rb`

```
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable threaded mode
  # config.threadsafe! unless $rails_rake_task

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  # config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5


  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "74.125.129.109",
  # :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port => 587,
  :domain => "localhost",
  :authentication => 'plain',
  :user_name => '~~~',
  :password => '~~~' ,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  :openssl_verify_mode  => 'none'
  }
```

Comment: Are sidekiq and redis running?

Comment: yes! sidekiq is runnig